# oxydized NE IPA?

Tags: ipa

Been brewing for about a year, I've got about a dozen brews under my belt. Tried my hand at a New England IPA. All went ok up to drinking it. When i bottled it (I bottle condition), the beer was the correct hazy pale yellow colour. Smell was nice and fruity/tropical. However, just under 2 weeks later, cracked open the first bottle and its gone bad.
Specifically, the fruity aroma has generally been replaced with a rather hoppy aroma and it leaves a massive bitter after taste in the mouth. colour has veered to the grayish spectrum.
I believe it has badly oxydized, probably due to my bottle conditioning and how i did it. Is my interpretation reasonable based on above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% correct.  Its unfortunate, but everyone who bottles traditionally by racking into a bucket with some sugar etc etc has a tough time with the beer oxidizing.  Some solutions would be to dose a sugar solution into the bottles independently.  Then use a CO2 regulator to push the beer out of a carboy into the bottles through a racking cane setup.  But then you need more equipment and might as well keg at that point.  Another option would be to experiment with the addition of metabisulfites at bottling.  I don't know the exact dosage but some are experimenting with the MBS and its ability to scavange some oxygen at bottling.  This is a tough style to bottle in an open environment.

Comment: Maybe emphasize the fact that it is NEIPA which is really difficult to bottle like this. I bottle beers from simple blondes to complex dark ones using a bottling bucket and sugar, and all my beers taste fine and still have a correct color, even after a year.